# Spring : Images won't load with Etag in IE

Tags: java, spring, internet-explorer, etag

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which I have Etag functionality for loading images. It's working for all other browsers except everyones favorite IE-11. The images appear as broken links. WHat am I doing wrong?

Code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getminipreview")
    @ResponseBody
    public int getminipreview(){

     Calendar inOneMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
            inOneMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            Path path;

      if(file!=null) {
                String etag = "";
                File etagFile = new File("/etag/file/location");
                if(!etagFile.exists()){
                   etag = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                     (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                            new FileOutputStream(etagFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
                        writer.write(etag);
                        response.addHeader("Etag",etag);
                    }

                }else {
                    etag = new String(Files.readAllBytes(etagFile.toPath()));
                    response.addHeader("Etag",etag);
                }

                response.setHeader("Cache-Control" , "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
                response.setContentType("image/png");
                response.setDateHeader("Expires",inOneMonth.getTimeInMillis());
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "image.png" + "\"");
                response.addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff");
                response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
                response.setContentLength((int) Files.size(path));
                Files.copy(path, response.getOutputStream());
            }
```

Comment: You've said that the code works in other browsers except IE. I think the server code is correct. This may be because of the settings in IE. Could you check that if there is any information on F12 developer tools's console tab? And in Network, could you check that if there is any avaliable status of the image?